# How do I check SQLite3 syntax?

Tags: sqlite, syntax-checking

Is there a way to check the syntax of a SQLite3 script without running it?

Basically, I'm looking for the SQLite3 equivalent of `ruby -c script.rb`, `perl -c script.pl`, `php --syntax-check script.php`, etc.

I've thought of using `explain`, but most of the scripts I'd like to check are kept around for reference purposes (and don't necessarily have an associated database).  Using `explain` would also make it hard to use with something like [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736).  (That is, I'm only wanting to check *syntax*, not *semantics*.)

**Update:**

I'm confused.  Let's say I want to syntax check this:

```
select * from foo;
```

I could do something like:

```
echo 'explain select * from foo;' | sqlite3
```

But then I get:

```
SQL error near line 1: no such table: foo
```

All I'd expect to see is "Syntax OK" (or something similar).  Is that possible?

Comment: This is close to what I'm thinking of: http://developer.mimer.se/validator/parser200x/index.tml#parser

Comment: That link is dead. The question in the OP seems important, as SQLite will not inform the user of lots of kinds of errors. Misspelled PRAGMAs, for instance, are simply ignored, which seems insane to me.

Answer (score 2):

A syntax checker that works well for me so far is the Ruby gem [`sqlint`](https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlint)

It checks ANSI SQL: it is not specific to the `sqlite` dialect.

*It came out in 2015, 5 years after the question was asked*

It needs Ruby and a C compiler (to build the `pg_query` native extension.)

Here is an example of output:

`$ sqlint ex7a.sql 
ex7a.sql:81:10:ERROR syntax error at or near "*"`

In the true Unix tradition, if the syntax is correct, sqlint produces no output. As the questioner asked, it doesn't check if tables exist.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I became aware of `sqlint` a couple of weeks ago, but your answer got me to actually install it and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you can use the [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) keyword.  It will return information about how the statement would be executed had you omitted the preceding EXPLAIN keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use EXPLAIN against an in memory database. With sqlite3, you can get an in memory database by passing ":memory:" as the filename to sqlite3_open_v2().